# How scanf() reading unformatted input?

Tags: c

Explain the output in this case when string is not formatted but still [scanf()](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdio.h/scanf) is able to read integers from an input string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
int n;
while (scanf("%d", & n))
    printf("%d\n", n);
return 0;
}
```

**Example Input:**

`1 2 3       4    5   54    34    abcd`

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
54
34
```

Input is so messy but output is still clean. How scanf() is working?

Answer (score 4):

For the `"%d"` specifier it will ignore whitespace characters, and then when it reaches the invalid characters `non-digit` it will return `0`, for each numeric value it returns `1` which is the number of specifiers successfully matched.

Read [here](http://www.manpages.info/linux/scanf.3.html) for more information.

Comment: Only leading whitespace characters or trailing whitespace characters also?

Comment: `scanf("%d",&n);` 'printf("%d",n);' I used these two statements inside my `main()` function and It's giving correct output in both cases Input-1: `[space][space][space]12` Input-2: `12[space][space][space]` Am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: @DeepakUniyal ,What's the output in both the cases? Isn't it 12?

Comment: Yes you are, the spaces still in the buffer, `scanf` does not care about them, try reading them with `fgetc()` and see what I mean, `scanf` didn't consume the trailing whitspaces.

Comment: Yes it is 12 but I was thinking when I am giving trailing spaces why it is not considering it as invalid input?

Comment: I think you are right, it's ignoring both, I am reading the manual but there seems to be no mention of trailing whitespaces, it just says **ignores whitespace chracters**.

Comment: @DeepakUniyal I fixed my answer, you are right it ignores both., because it wouldn't make sense to consider **trailing** whitespace characters, they could be leading for the next valid character, so it will ignore whitespace, just ignore them.

Comment: @iharob, `scanf` in the OP's example won't even notice the leading whitespaces. It gets the number and when it is called the next time, it becomes trailing whitespaces which the `%d` ignores and waits for the user to input an integer.

Comment: @CoolGuy yes you are right, if you mean _it becomes **leading** whitespace_.

Comment: @iharob ,err. I get confused over leading and trailing whitespace. Is `123 ` a leading whitespace?

Comment: @CoolGuy No, it's trailing.

Comment: @iharob ,I thought that since 'leading' means "in front of" that is a leading whitespace. Thanks for clarifying it. Just consider 'leading' to be 'trailing' and vice-versa in my second comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68881/discussion-between-iharob-and-cool-guy).

Comment: @CoolGuy: assume the input stream contains `"  123  456"`; `scanf("%d", n);` will read *and discard* the leading spaces, then read and convert `"123"`.  It stops reading when it sees the first non-digit character (in this case, the first space after `123`).  The input stream will now contain `"  456"`.  Does that help?

Comment: @iharob , Sorry. I can't chat because I'm using a very old phone which supports SO partially.

Comment: @JohnBode, So is it appropriate to say that that `scanf` does not consume trailing whitespace (while it consumes leading whitespaces) and scans everything until encountering it?

Comment: @CoolGuy: It depends on the conversion specifier used.  *Most* conversion specifiers tell `scanf` to consume leading whitespace; the exceptions are `%c` and `%[`.  Check your handy C reference manual for details.

Answer (score 3):

`scanf("%d", &n)` would return 1 (number of values read succesfully) for integers and would fail when it encounters non-digits and would break the `while`

Answer (score 1):

scanf ignore the blank characters such as:

```
\t(ASCII:0x09) 
\n(ASCII:0x0a)
blank(ASCII:0x20)
```

ref: [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/?kw=scanf)

> Whitespace character: the function will read and ignore any whitespace
>   characters encountered before the next non-whitespace character
>   (whitespace characters include spaces, newline and tab characters --
>   see isspace). A single whitespace in the format string validates any
>   quantity of whitespace characters extracted from the stream (including
>   none).

Comment: `scanf` might or might not skip it. This depends upon the format specifier.

Answer (score 0):

In c programming language data type is strictly defined . You have to enter proper data in scanf() function . In you enter any wrong type then it will return 0 that means false . 
Try to do like this . The mechanism will be clear to you .

```
#include <stdio.h>
int n,m;
int main()
{
    do{
        m = scanf("%d",&n);
        printf("Legality: %d  Value: %d\n",m,n);
    }while(m);
    return 0;
}
```